# Unexpected output with pivot_tables in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was following this [blogpost](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html) when I found this behaviour in Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
df.columns = ["admit", "gre", "gpa", "prestige"]
pd.pivot_table(df,values='admit',rows=['admit'], cols=['prestige'],aggfunc='count')
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

but instead, if you refer to the rows and columns as `df['admit'], df['prestige']`, you get the expected result:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values='admit',rows=df['admit'], cols=df['prestige'],aggfunc='count')
prestige   1   2   3   4
admit                   
0         28  97  93  55
1         33  54  28  12
```

According to the documentation, I should be able to refer to the DataFrame only using column's names in a list or array. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to create that pivot table with 'size' as the aggregating function:

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table(rows='admit', cols='prestige', aggfunc='size')
Out[11]: 
prestige   1   2   3   4
admit                   
0         28  97  93  55
1         33  54  28  12
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's more reasonable but the documentation says that I should be able to use lists and arrays.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think pandas was confused by 'admit' in both `values` and `rows`, but didn't dig into it further.